# Gerrit to gerrit replication cannot view refs/changes

Tags: gerrit

This issue has been troubling me for a while. I have set up gerrit replication recently.

After sync started, everything else works fine, branches are synced, tags are synced. However even I explicitly set to replicate refs/changes, and I see it is in logs too, I'm unable to find it in the replication server.

Gerrit version: 2.12

Replication version 2.12

replication.config:

```
[remote "hostname"] 
  url = gerrit2@remotehostname.com:/gerrit/review_site/git/myproject.git 
  projects = myproject
  push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
  push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
  push = +refs/changes/*:refs/changes/*
```

replication.log has this:

[2018-05-03 12:02:33,783] [b4044bc4] Replication to gerrit2@remote-hostname.com:/gerrit/review_site/git/myproject.git started...

[2018-05-03 12:02:34,425] [b4044bc4] Push to gerrit2@remote-hostname.com:/gerrit/review_site/git/myproject.git references: [RemoteRefUpdate[remoteName=refs/changes/79/64079/11, NOT_ATTEMPTED, (null)...f6e058179c5253366fd6e81fcda079cdf2212034, srcRef=refs/changes/79/64079/11, forceUpdate, message=null]]

[2018-05-03 12:02:57,987] [] scheduling replication myproject:/changes/25/64325/4 => gerrit2@remote-hostname:/gerrit/review_site/git/myproject.git

[2018-05-03 12:02:57,988] [] scheduled myproject:refs/changes/25/64325/4 => [74c813f5] push gerrit2@remote-hostname:/gerrit/review_site/git/myproject.git to run after 15s

[2018-05-03 12:04:01,384] [b4044bc4] Replication to gerrit2@remote-hostname.com:/gerrit/review_site/git/myproject.git completed in 87601ms, 15001ms delay, 0 retries

Everything seems succeeded

I started the replication with command:`ssh -p 29418 localhost replication start`

I tried to push a CL to the replication server and I'm able to do so and see the CL from UI. So I assume there is no permission issue on this
Besides I did not find anything synced under `/gerrit/review_site/git/myproject.git/refs/changes`
If we cannot have refs/changes synced, it would not be possible to fail over on slave if master is down.

Anyone has seen this issue and can help me understand why?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

We figured it out. It is because the database was not replicated properly. After we successfully replicated the database, all the ref changes are showed up correctly.